# function from one dll calling the same name function of another dll

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a peculiar problem. I have two DLLs, let's call them DLL-A and DLL-B.

DLL-A has a function named `f1()` and DLL-B also has function with the same name, `f1()`. Now in DLL-A, `f1()` is calling `f1()` of DLL-B like this.

**DLL-A**:

```
f1()
{
    f1(); //this is DLL-B function, but having the same name
}
```

Now my question is that, will it be a recursive call of `f1()` from DLL-A?

Answer (score 7):

The `f1()` inside the function body calls itself leading to an infinite recursion, as you suspected. Some possible solutions:

- Put the imported DLL function in a separate namespace so that you can distinguish its name.
- Change the names of these function to avoid a clash.
- Import *explicitly* rather than *implicitly* by using `GetProcAddress`. That allows you to call the imported function anything you like.

Answer (score 7):

You can change the name of the function in DLL-A to `A_f1`.

```
A_f1()
{
  f1() //this calls DLL-B's f1
}
```

In your DEF file, write

```
EXPORTS
    f1 = A_f1
```

This says "The function I internally called `A_f1` should be exported under the name `f1` to other components." That way everybody who had been using DLL-A and calls `f1` (expecting to get the function A) will get `A_f1`.

I'm assuming that renaming the exported functions is not possible. If it is possible, then that is a much cleaner solution. (My guess is that it isn't possible because you are trying to hack a video game.)

Comment: Nice comment about hacking a video game

Answer (score 3):

They way you have written it **f1 within f1** will not call DLL-B but be a infinite recursion. If you want to call DLL-B function you will have to use **GetProcAddress**

Answer (score 2):

You should get a compiler or linker error if you link two objects files that export the same symbol. Something like "multiple definition for symbol f1()".

That is, of course, if you include in one dll the header that declares the other function or link the two binaries together.

To resolve this, place the functions inside namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can change the name by:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:MyFunc=_MyFunc@8")
```